# Рабы и продукты — деньги, валюта?

Tags: семантика

Можно ли сказать, что в рабовладельческом обществе рабы — это валюта, деньги? Или что, например, при первобытно-общинном строе деньгами, валютой являлись натуральные продукты? Или понятия "валюта", "деньги" применяются по отношению к бумажным, металлическим знакам?

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что "валютой" назвать можно. В Нацкорпусе несколько раз раз встречаются похожие выражения, например:

- > В первый раз он оказался здесь в 1988 году, когда «сигареты Marlboro
  > были валютой и ими можно было расплачиваться в такси».
- > ...в сущности билеты сами были валютой особого рода, на них можно
  > было, к примеру, выменять томик дефицитной тогда фантастики из
  > знаменитой серии издательства «Мир»...
- > ...мёд в восемнадцатом году был валютой более надежной.

Что касается денег, то я не нашёл примеров, но чисто технически, отталкиваясь от [банковского определения термина "деньги"](https://www.banki.ru/wikibank/dengi_wiki/), ими можно назвать любое средство измерения стоимости, хоть кандибобиков:

> Деньги – средство оплаты товаров и услуг, средство измерения
> стоимости, а также средство сохранения стоимости.